# What's the easiest way to adjust a module intended for 5 players so that it can accommodate 6 players?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, balance

I'm playing with a 6 character group in the H series of modules, Keep on the Shadowfell and Thunderspire labyrinth, which are both intended for 5 players.

Frankly the combats are usually too easy, sometimes the DM adds an additional monster to the mix, but not on every encounter.  I would hate for him to have to break every fight down to xp and then rebalance them all.

Is there some easy way to rebalance 5-player modules for 6-players?

Comment: Incidentally, are you using the Monster Manual 3 damage update?  I found fights were too easy until I started applying it.  With it, I can stick strictly to the budget and expect a good fight that knocks someone unconscious, but doesn't kill anyone.

Comment: Easy solution: kill a player! :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Add one standard monster (or 4 minions) to every encounter.

This will give you the right XP by the book to add to the encounter in order to account for the additional player.

I would recommend adding monsters from the following groups:

- **minions**  (If the party has a couple AoE's, adding more than 4 should be OK).  When in doubt add minions, particularly minions whose level is 1 under the party.  You can add a **lot** of those guys and let the party go to town on 'em.
- **skirmishers** (can generally move and keep the battlefield fluid, threaten the back lines)
- **brute**  (high damage, but low defenses. These will keep combat fast and exciting)
- **lurker** (Keep the back line of the party really nervous)

And not recommend adding these too often:

- **controller** (tend to apply deleterious status effects and/or restrict movement. Too many of those aren't fun)
- **soldier** (these guys are a pain to deal with.  Too many can bog down combat)

These should almost never be added:

- **elite** (too much xp)
- **solo** (WAY too much xp)

Comment: Also remember to increase the amount of treasure that is given.  If you're using the parcel system, the DMG recommends an additional magical item of level + 2 per level.

Answer (score 2):

The DMG says to budget 20% more XP for a fight with 6 players instead of 5.  Instead of redoing the fight entirely, I think he should clone the monster whose XP is closest to 20%.